# Asp.Net Core Middleware service dependent on current User

Tags: asp.net-core

I would like to either change a request scoped service or set one in a custom middleware layer.

Specifically, I want to be able to do something like the below contrived example  in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection service)
{
    service.AddScoped<IMyUserDependentService>((provider) => {
        return new MyService());
    });
}

public void Configure(...) {

    //other config removed

    app.Use(async (context, next) => {

        var myService = context.ApplicationServices.GetService<IMyUserDependentService>();


        myService.SetUser(context.User.Identity.Name);//Name is Fred

        next.Invoke();
    });
}
```

Then in the controller do this:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public HomeController(IMyUserDependentService myService)
    {
        //myService.UserName should equal Fred
    }
}
```

The problem is, that this doesn't work. myService.UserName isn't Fred in controller, it's null. I think that the IOC container is creating a new instance in the controller, and not using the one set in the middleware.

If I change the scope of the service to Transient, Fred is remembered, but that doesn't help because the service is dependent on who the current user is.

To recap, what I need is to create/or edit a service that requires the current user (or other current request variables), but am unable to work this out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I think that the IOC container is creating a new instance in the controller, and not using the one set in the middleware." You can verify this by putting a breakpoint in the `IMyUserDependentService` constructor and seeing if it gets instantiated more than once during a request.

Comment: Interestingly, for the controller a new service is being created each time, but inside the middleware `.use` method the service is the same one as the previous request.....wtf?

Comment: In that case it sounds like your middleware is somewhere in the pipeline before the "scope" gets created.

Comment: it's the second to last thing in the pipeline, the last is app.UseMVC..? Startup.ConfigureServices definitely gets called before Startup.Configure (where middleware is set).

Comment: Thanks for the tip @danludwig! I had `app.Use` before `app.UseIdentity()`, and hence I was getting `false` for `context.User.IsSignedIn()`, when tht was not the case..

Comment: Important to note, the Use must be before UseMvc in the setup in order for the setup to have occurred before the MVC request is processed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using `context.RequestServices`?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue, I got an error like 
`InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'IScopedService' from root provider.`, the exception thrown was very not well documented.

Here is how I solved it:

[Startup.cs]

```
services.AddScoped<IAnyScopedService, AnyScopedService>();
services.AddSingleton<ISomeOtherSingletonService, SomeOtherSingletonService>();
```

[MyMiddleware.cs]

```
public sealed class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ISomeOtherSingletonService _Svc;

    public MyMiddleware(
              RequestDelegate next,
              ISomeOtherSingletonService svc)
    {
        _next = next;
        _Svc = svc;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context,
              IAnyScopedService scopedService)
    {
        // Some work with scoped service
    }
}
```

Indeed the Middleware is instanciated only once, but called many times. 
The constructor takes therefore singleton instances, where the invoke method can get scoped injected parameters.

More details on [Mark Vincze post](https://blog.markvincze.com/two-gotchas-with-scoped-and-singleton-dependencies-in-asp-net-core/)